# Assignment Problem

Tags: c#

my problem is that for some reason, a simple assignment isn't working.
the dataGridView is binded to DB and im trying to assign a value type string to a column of type string

```
enter code here //the initialization of the DataGridView     
   bindingSourceSchema.DataSource = null;
        dgwSchema.Columns["colID"].DataPropertyName = "APP_ID";
        dgwSchema.Columns["colName"].DataPropertyName = "DESCRIPTION";
        dgwSchema.Columns["colTextbox"].DataPropertyName = "APP_ARGS";
        dgwSchema.Columns["colTextbox"].HeaderText = "Parameters";          
        dgwSchema.Columns["colLink"].DataPropertyName = "APP_PATH";
        dgwSchema.Columns["colLink"].HeaderText = "Path";

        DataGridViewLinkColumn colLink = (DataGridViewLinkColumn)dgwSchema.Columns["colLink"];
        colLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
        colLink.Text = "Edit";
        bindingSourceSchema.DataSource = SchemaDB.GetGenericApps();//the assignment
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                dgwSchema.CurrentRow.Cells["colLink"].Value = openFileDialog.FileName;

                // !! ?? dgwSchema.CurrentRow.Cells["colLink"].Value STAYS with parameter "Edit"
            }
```

Thanks
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with where you are running this code.  Is this in the PageLoad event?  Make sure the grid is not being bound again after you do this.  What does the debugger show you if you put a break point after the assignment?

Comment: it's not in a page load event, & the grid isn't bounded again afterward..
the debugger shows that the value hasn't changed BUT, now i see that 
dgwSchema.CurrentRow.Cells["colLink"].OwningRow.DataBoundItem -> Row.ItemArray
the value has changed and RowState = Modified (when i change it on run time)
so actually the only thing left is to change the Value that is shown in GUI, but that for some reason isn't changing..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is following property is set to true.

colLink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;

Set it to false. Then it will resolve your problem.